# Stripe webhook is giving status 200, but the NodeJs function is not firing

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe webhook that fires after a payment is succesfull. The webhook gives a 200 status (succesfull) in the Stripe dashboard log, yet nothing happens in my code. I have a console.log(req.body) in the function, but the console.log is not shown in the CLI. When I console.log outside of the webhook function it does show, so I asume the function isn't being called. This seems strange to me..

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
      next();
    } else {
      bodyParser.json()(req, res, next);
    }
  });

  app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    let sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    try {
        let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
       
        res.status(200).end()

        // Do something with event
        console.log(req.bodyRaw)
        console.log(event);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).end()
    }
});
```

I use Google cloud functions in combination with Node JS/Express.

Comment: Are you sure this code is being called when expected? If you change `res.status(200).end()` to `res.send('Testing Stripe webhooks!')` and trigger another event, does `Testing Stripe webhooks!` show up in the body of the response from your server in the Stripe Dashboard?

Comment: I've changed the response as you have suggested and the respons is being recieved in the Stripe dashboard. o the function is triggered and responding. I feel like I'm missing something very basic about the console.log not being shown in CLI..

Comment: `res.end()` will instantly end the response process, therefore this is complete non-sense.... and also, `console.log()` behaves a whole lot different than on the client-side; try [`node-monkey`](https://github.com/jwarkentin/node-monkey) or [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)instead.

Comment: Well, for Cloud Functions, see https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/logs?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com

Comment: Yes I noticed the console.logs where after the .end(). When I put them in front nothing changed. I tried to write the event object to my database and that works, so the problem is I'm not familiar with using console.log inside a function like this. I'll look up cloud functions link to learn about it. The confusion for me was that it that console.log does work outside of the function scope.