# NodeJS function inside of Stripe Webhook does not fire when using Serverless

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, webhooks, serverless

**Objective**: Host an endpoint with Serverless for a Stripe webhook that fires off an email when the `charge.refunded` event occurs.

*Issue*: NodeJS function does not fire properly inside of Serverless implementation of Stripe Webhook.

*Background*: I implemented the below code outside of a [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/) implementation following this [Stripe Webhook guide](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart) and was able to successfully identify the event in my local dev env and fire off the email.

However, once I moved and stripped out the server code (express) for my `handler.js` file within my Serverless app, the `sendEmail` function no longer fires as the function does not enter the `charge.refunded` case. I tested this by adding my generated endpoint for the webhook into Stripe and testing the event from there. Upon firing the `charge.refunded` event in Stripe, I get back a successful response and my Serverless logs pick up on the API call, yet `sendEmail` is never reached.

Please help!

**EDIT**: Final Working Code Below

```
"use strict";
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_');
const formData = require('form-data');
const Mailgun = require('mailgun.js');

module.exports.webhook = async (event) => {

  async function sendEmail() {

    const mailgun = new Mailgun(formData);

    const mg = mailgun.client({
      username: 'api',
      key: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
      public_key: process.env.MAILGUN_PUBLIC_KEY
    });

    let messageParams = {
      from: 'mailgun@domain.com',
      to: 'me@domain.com',
      subject: 'Hello',
      text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!',
  }

    const result = await mg.messages.create(
      'sandbox-123.mailgun.org',
      messageParams
      ).then((msg) => console.log(msg))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    
    return result
  }

  try {

  const eventBody = JSON.parse(event.body)

  switch (eventBody.type) {
    case "charge.refunded":
      const charge = eventBody.data.object;
      await sendEmail()
      console.log('charge refunded!')
      break;
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      console.log(`bad request:${request}`)
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: "Your function executed successfully!",
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };


  } catch (err) {
    //console.log('ERROR:', err)
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          message: "Your function errored",
          error: err,
        },
        null,
        2
      ),
    };

  }
  
};
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150532/stripe-webhook-is-giving-status-200-but-the-nodejs-function-is-not-firing) seems similar to mine, but is unresolved.

Edit: Here is the test request that Stripe sends for the event.

```
{
  "created": 121351351231,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "charge.refunded",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": "2020-08-27",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "ch_00000000000000",
      "object": "charge",
      "amount": 2000,
      "amount_captured": 2000,
      "amount_refunded": 2000,
      "application": null,
      "application_fee": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "balance_transaction": "txn_00000000000000",
      "billing_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": null,
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": null,
          "state": null
        },
        "email": null,
        "name": null,
        "phone": null
      },
      "calculated_statement_descriptor": "Stripe",
      "captured": true,
      "created": 1639014132,
      "currency": "usd",
      "customer": null,
      "description": "(created by Stripe CLI)",
      "disputed": false,
      "failure_code": null,
      "failure_message": null,
      "fraud_details": {
      },
      "invoice": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "order": null,
      "outcome": {
        "network_status": "approved_by_network",
        "reason": null,
        "risk_level": "normal",
        "risk_score": 54,
        "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
        "type": "authorized"
      },
      "paid": true,
      "payment_intent": "pi_00000000000000",
      "payment_method": "pm_00000000000000",
      "payment_method_details": {
        "card": {
          "brand": "visa",
          "checks": {
            "address_line1_check": null,
            "address_postal_code_check": null,
            "cvc_check": null
          },
          "country": "US",
          "exp_month": 12,
          "exp_year": 2022,
          "fingerprint": "skdjndsf54sdf",
          "funding": "credit",
          "installments": null,
          "last4": "4242",
          "network": "visa",
          "three_d_secure": null,
          "wallet": null
        },
        "type": "card"
      },
      "receipt_email": null,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/",
      "refunded": true,
      "refunds": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "re_00000000000000",
            "object": "refund",
            "amount": 2000,
            "balance_transaction": "txn_00000000000000",
            "charge": "ch_00000000000000",
            "created": 12315364531,
            "currency": "usd",
            "metadata": {
            },
            "payment_intent": null,
            "reason": null,
            "receipt_number": "1759-4625",
            "source_transfer_reversal": null,
            "status": "succeeded",
            "transfer_reversal": null
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/charges/ch_3K4beCGEYqkKFGst0peRnNQE/refunds"
      },
      "review": null,
      "shipping": {
        "address": {
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "country": "US",
          "line1": "510 Townsend St",
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": "94103",
          "state": "CA"
        },
        "carrier": null,
        "name": "Jenny Rosen",
        "phone": null,
        "tracking_number": null
      },
      "source_transfer": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null,
      "fee": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the abbreviated output of `console.log(event.body)`:

```
event.body {
    "created": 0000000000,
    "livemode": false,
    "id": "evt_00000000000000",
    "type": "charge.refunded",
    "object": "event",
    "request": null,
    "pending_webhooks": 1,
    "api_version": "2020-08-27",
    "data": {
        "object": {
            ...
            },
            "description": "(created by Stripe CLI)",
            "disputed": false,
            "outcome": {
                "network_status": "approved_by_network",
                "reason": null,
                "risk_level": "normal",
                "risk_score": 54,
                "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
                "type": "authorized"
            },
            "paid": true,
            "payment_intent": "pi_00000000000000",
            "payment_method": "pm_00000000000000",
            "payment_method_details": {
                "card": {
                    "brand": "visa",
                    "checks": {
                        "address_line1_check": null,
                        "address_postal_code_check": null,
                        "cvc_check": null
                    },
                    "country": "US",
                    "exp_month": 12,
                    "exp_year": 2022,
                    "fingerprint": "000000",
                    "funding": "credit",
                    "installments": null,
                    "last4": "4242",
                    "network": "visa",
                    "three_d_secure": null,
                    "wallet": null
                },
                "type": "card"
            },
            "receipt_email": null,
            "receipt_number": "1809-0178",
            "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_/ch_/",
            "refunded": true,
            "refunds": {
                "object": "list",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "re_00000000000000",
                        "object": "refund",
                        "amount": 2000,
                        "balance_transaction": "txn_00000000000000",
                        "charge": "ch_00000000000000",
                        "created": 0000000,
                        "currency": "usd",
                        "metadata": {},
                        "payment_intent": null,
                        "reason": null,
                        "receipt_number": "1917-1209",
                        "source_transfer_reversal": null,
                        "status": "succeeded",
                        "transfer_reversal": null
                    }
                ],
                "has_more": false,
                "url": "/v1/charges/ch_0000000/refunds"
            },
            "review": null,
            "shipping": {
                "address": {
                    "city": "San Francisco",
                    "country": "US",
                    "line1": "510 Townsend St",
                    "line2": null,
                    "postal_code": "94103",
                    "state": "CA"
                },
                "carrier": null,
                "name": "Jenny Rosen",
                "phone": null,
                "tracking_number": null
            },
            "source_transfer": null,
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
            "status": "succeeded",
            "transfer_data": null,
            "transfer_group": null,
            "fee": 0
        }
    }
}
```

The output for `console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(event.body).type))` is `"charge.refunded"` yet the case for it in the switch statement is not entered. Why?

[Here is a picture from the Cloudwatch logs to confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFYTS.png)

Comment: Are you deploying to AWS Lambda? Then why are you using `express` and `app.post`? You don't need that. Your `async (event) => { ...` is the equivalent of `app.post`

Comment: @derpirscher Great call, I stripped the express code and edited the above code snippet to reflect the current state. When testing Stripe's webhook, it is sent successfully, but the `sendEmail()` function does not fire like it did outside of a serverless implementation. Got any thoughts on this?

Comment: `sendEmail` is an asynchronous function.

Comment: You have to `await sendEmail()`. An async lambda function (and all it's pending promises) will be terminated once you `return ...`

Comment: @derpirscher I had an `await` inside of `sendEmail()` where the message was created and I've also now added it where the function itself is invoked (edited above), but it still does not fire. 

I also just tested my code again outside of a serverless implementation running on express() and the email fired immediately. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @hoangdv `sendEmail()` is an asynchronous function, but it is behaving differently in a serverless implementation vs running a local server. Why would that be?

Comment: @quantum1125 in aws env, your function will finish immediately, before the email is sent. On your local side, the function is also finished immediately, but the local server still runs, then the email will be sent after the function is finished.

Comment: Is the send email function not called at all, or does the email not get sent? I'm wondering if, eg, you're missing your MG secrets in the configured env vars.

Comment: can you verify you see the outputs of `console.log('charge',charge); console.log('charge refunded!')` in your lambda function's log? If *yes*, then `sendMail()` is called for sure, and will -- a far as I can see -- also be awaited. Maybe the environment variables holding your mailgun key are not set correctly? If *no* then either your `endPointSecret` is not set or the `event.type` is not `charge.refunded`. You should also add some exception handling around your event handler, so that in case of an exception you can return a well-defined result ...

Comment: @hoangdv great insight, so how do I force the lambda function within the aws env to not end before the email is sent? I am already using `async` and `await`.

Comment: @quantum1125 `return mg.messages.create...`

Comment: @BrendanMoore On my local server, the email gets sent. In this aws env, it does not. My MG creds are configured as env vars in my aws console already as well being passed in the code as a backstop for now.

Comment: @hoangdv I am already doing that, just forgot to update that in the code above (updated now). Any other thoughts? Really at a loss here of how else to keep the function from ending.

Comment: @derpirscher Only my local server to do i see the outputs of those `console.log` requests. But I don't in see them in my lambda function log, I only see a giant hash(?) like this
```{  "c": true,
      "b": "H4sIAAAAAAAAA7VWbU/jOBD+K..." }```

I have set the env variables for MG correctly, the `endpointSecret` is set but not necessary. The `event.type` is `charge.refunded` as I am originating it from the stripe dashboard to test. Any other thoughts on what could be going on?

Comment: @derpirscher is there supposed to be a way to see those console logs in my lambda function's log? could be a promising lead

Comment: @quantum1125 if you connect the lambda with API gateway, `event.type` is not the correct way to get the webhook data, try printout `console.log(JSON.stringify(event.body))`

Comment: @hoangdv you are correct, event.type was the incorrect way to access the webhook data. Taking a look above at the added code for the output of event, what do you believe to be the correct syntax to access type within body within event? 

The output for `console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(event.body).type))` is `"charge.refunded"` yet the case for it in the switch statement is not entered. Why?

Comment: As already said: There are three possibilities, why your switch isn't entered: 1. there is some exception happening before the switch (ie add some exception handling and return a meaningful result on an exception) 2. `endpointSecret` isn't set (and thus the body of `if (endPointsecret) {... }` which contains the `switch` isn't executed) 3. the expression you are `switch`ing on isn't what  you expect it to be.

Comment: And please update the code in the question to the code your current code. Because none of the above code can produce the mentioned output `{"c":true,"b":"K78s8fjskA7VWbU/cOBD\{...}","origin":"sls-agent"}` and your shown code is still accessing the `event.type` property, which is wrong. Furthermore what is that `return email` doing there after `await sendEmail()`? This will terminate the lambdafunction without sending a meaningful result ...

Comment: @derpirscher Apologies, the code is now updated and shows the `request` that is being passed to the switch statement. The `{"c":..}` output I mentioned earlier is due to a serverless log, not a manual `console.log`. I believe it's a hash of some creds. I've also removed the `return email` code, this was used when I believed the `sendEmail` was firing, which I know is not happening.

Comment: So once again: Do you see any of the outputs in the block of `case 'charge.refunded'`? Do you have any meaningful exception handling so you can verify your handler is not throwing any exception? As said numerous times: If that is the code you are using there are only 3 possiblities, why `sendEmail` wouldnt be called: 1. you have an unhandled exception, 2. `endpointSecret` isn't a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) 3. the `request` in `switch (request)` is not what you think it is ...

Comment: @derpirscher I had originally removed `endpointSecret` because I wasn't checking for a match with `stripe-signature` anyway as I was testing. It just makes the code more secure to check for this logic before firing any actions. Its absence doesn't change the outcome of the code. At this point, I see no outputs from `charge.refunded` case. I have implemented exception handling now (see edited code) and have confirmed via the Cloudwatch logs that `request` is `charge.refunded` (see screenshot at bottom of post). At this point,  no exceptions are being thrown so not sure what is next to try?

Comment: @derpirscher I really appreciate the patience and time you've put into helping me. Grateful for all your insights and continued persistence to help me debug.

Comment: the error is in this line `const request = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(event.body).type)`. `let x = JSON.stringify(...)` of a `string` produces literally `"foo bar"`, ie the value of the variable contains the quotes. So your request is not `'charge.refunded'` but `'"charge.refunded"'`. There is no need for that `JSON.stringify` because `JSON.parse(event.body).type` already returns the correct value as a string ...

Comment: I'd suggest to do something like `const eventbody = JSON.parse(event.body)`.  Now you have a json object, containing your payload from stripe and can access all properties of that body without any further ado. You probably will need more than just `eventbody.type` but also for instance `eventbody.data.object`. So you can now do  `switch (eventbody.type)` and it will have the correct value, you expect

Comment: @derpirscher Ah you are correct. I had your implementation earlier but it was still failing to what I now know to be a bad `console.log` in the `charge.refunded` case. The email fires now. You've been immensely helpful. Thank you! I've updated the code in the post to reflect final version (not verifying signature atm).